# SimpleXML & html entities = strange characters

Tags: php, utf-8, simplexml, html-entities

I am getting a feed as such..

```
$posts = new SimpleXMLElement(WP_ROOT_URL . 'feed/', 0, true);
```

In this feed one of the items I am getting contains a html entity, which is the entity for the "hyphen character", which is `&#8211;`

However when this is returned from SimpleXML all I get is a `â€“`. I have read other similar questions on SO & some mention to make sure your page is set to `UTF-8`; though not sure how this will stop SimpleXML from returning the strange character?

Any which way I do have this on the page the data is output on:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

What can I do here to get the correct entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP strings don't have unified or managed encoding, therefore you cannot think of them as containing characters but bytes. The result always contains the bytes `0xE28093`, only the interpretation changes. You can see this by calling `bin2hex()` on the result.

The bytes interpreted in Windows-1252 come out as `â€“`, interpreted in UTF-8, they come out as `–`.

If you are echoing this on a web page, then you can make browser interpret your output in UTF-8 by doing:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"); //Put this before any output
echo "stuff";
```